Javacript monorepo: How to organize barrel files to avoid unnecessary imports and cyclical dependencies
We have a small mono-repo similar to the following:
- /core
  - package.json
  - tsconfig.json
    /src
    - index.ts (export/imports from components and utils)
    - /components
      - index.ts (export imports from componentA and B)
      - componentA.ts
      - componentB.ts
    - /utils 
      - index.ts (export imports from utilA and B)
      - utilA.ts
      - utilB.ts
- web
  - main.ts
  - package.json

When building core, the typescript files are transpiled to javascript files with a similar struture (index files and individual files). web can then import everything form root: import {componentA} from "@core";. From web, this is how I expect it to work.
However, the index files cause a few issues with core development. VSCode will automatically reference the index file reference (import {componentA} from "./compeonents" for automatic imports instead of the originating file (import {componentA} from "./compeonents/componentA". This quickly causes cyclical dependencies and, if tree shaking isn't working/available, can increase the heap usage (e.g., during jest testing) due to the unnecessary imports.
Is there an optimal way to organize this to overcome this issue? I want the index barrel files for external usage, but I want to make them essentially invisible for internal usage. This means I want the IDE to only import from the originator and an error to raise if importing from the index file.
Some approaches I've attempted:

use es-lint no-restricted-imports but this doesn't fix the auto-imports issue and I couldn't get the error to trigger on import ... from "./componenets" but not ... "./components/componentA"
Move the index files to a separate folder structure (barrelFiles next to src) and use the no-restricted-imports to prevent core imports to it. This works but now when I build (basic tsc at root of barrelFiles), I end up replicating barrelFiles and src folder structure in dist which then requires web imports to reference "barrelFiles" which is starting to feel hacky.

core/package.json:
{
  "name": "@core",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "/dist"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
  }
}


core/tsconfig.json
{
  "include": { "src/**/*"}
}

web/package.json
{
  "name": "web",
  "dependencies": {
    "@core": "file:../core"
  }
}


Can you share the config where you define path alias @core?

I added snippets from the json files, thanks!
